# Having problems in making JSONObjects in Java

Tags: java, json

my code to make my JSONObject is basically:

```
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

// Load the requested page converted to a string into a JSONObject.  
JSONObject myAwway = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));  

// Get the query value'  
String query = myAwway.getString("data");  

// Make array of the suggestions  
JSONArray suggestions = myAwway.getJSONArray("data");
```

This was working perfectly fine until a couple of minutes ago, when suddenly, it gives me the error "JSON failed"... any idea why?

Comment: I doubt all it said was "JSON failed". Stack trace?

Comment: Post the actual JSON document here, and I'm sure the problem will be immediately apparent.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
 String query = myAwway.getString("data");  
 JSONArray suggestions = myAwway.getJSONArray("data");
```

Wouldn't that mean that the item "data" of your Object is a String AND an array? That might be possible as long as its empty, so it might have worked (don't now this for sure). But it doesn't seem very right to get a String and a JSONArray from the same place.

- print out your `convertStreamToString(instream)` string. Does that give you a valid json string?
- if so, what's in there.. is the 'data' a string or an object?